# How can I change the color of the Android Action Bar?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-actionbar

I am trying to change the color of my Android ActionBar, but my app is closing with an error each time. I have tried all other suggestions and fixes in other posts, but they dont seem to work for me. Also - minSdkVersion 19

Error:

```
03-17 11:25:56.884  11999-11999/ca.holdfastonline.menu_test_02 E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: ca.holdfastonline.menu_test_02, PID: 11999
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{ca.holdfastonline.menu_test_02/ca.holdfastonline.menu_test_02.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2292)
```

My Styles.xml

```
<resources>
    <style name="QueryTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat">
        <!-- Any customizations for your app running on devices with Theme.Holo here -->
    </style>
    <!-- the theme applied to the application or activity -->
    <style name="CustomActionBarTheme"
        parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
    </style>

    <!-- ActionBar styles -->
    <style name="MyActionBar"
        parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse">
        <item name="android:background">#2980b9</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

My AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="ca.holdfastonline.menu_test_02" >

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/QueryTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/CustomActionBarTheme">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Thank you.

Comment: What is your minimum SDK?

Comment: @TristanWiley My minSdkVersion 19

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.
```

You have only one activity. It is using `@style/CustomActionBarTheme`. Your definition of `CustomActionBarTheme` has it inheriting from `Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar`. That is not an `AppCompat` theme. Change `Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar` to `Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar`.

Comment: And when @CommonsWare answers, you know that your answer will be always a useless answer

Comment: I changed what you mentioned and the app runs, but without any custom color?

Comment: @Holdfast33: That is because you have not changed anything in that theme. You are having the same results as if you used `Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar` directly. The answer that @Fondesa deleted showed you how to add `colorPrimary` to that theme to set the primary color, which will be used by `appcompat-v7` to tint your action bar. See [this directory](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/AppCompat) for a bunch of samples of using `appcompat-v7`, in particular the `ActionBarColor` one for setting up tints.

Comment: @CommonsWare Thank you for this answer. That clears it up perfectly. I added `<item name="colorPrimary">#2980b9</item>` under the CustomActionBarTheme and it worked. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

This is probably because in your Java file you are using ActionBarActivity and you should be using Activity.

**More Info**
Basically you are using ActionBarActivity, this activity requires a Theme.AppCompact which is where your error is coming from. To fix this you would need to change to use the regular Activity or just use Theme.AppCompact

Comment: Yes in my java file I do have 'ActionBarActivity' throughout. Should all instances of 'ActionBarActivity', be changed to just 'Activity'? Can you expand on your answer?

Comment: Basically you are using ActionBarActivity, this activity requires a Theme.AppCompact which is where your error is coming from. To fix this you would need to change to use the regular
    Activity
or just use Theme.AppCompact